# Queues in rabbit mq staying in idle state for longer time

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

In the rabbitmq service i have configured 8 queues, i am using spring client to send messages to rabbit MQ, i could be able to send messages to respective queues but at most of the times only a single queue is running and the rest of the queues are in idle state, to give turn to all queues i have reduced the configured the prefetch count to 20, so that all messages doesn't go to workers(consumers) and cause other queues to remain idle, in-spite of this i don't see multiple queues running parallel.

Below is the spring configuration i have used to set prefetch count

```
@Bean 
public CachingConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() throws Exception 
{
    com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory factory = new com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory(); 
    factory.setHost(host);
    factory.setUsername(username); 
    factory.setPassword(password);
    factory.setPort(5671);
    factory.useSslProtocol(); 
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(factory);
    return connectionFactory; 
}
```

---

i am different multiple container factory for each queue, some of them are mentioned below.(not sure why we use factories, my assumption is to give configuration like prefetch to queues)

```
    @Bean(name = "ordersimplecontainer") 
        public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleOrderListenerContainerFactory()  throws Exception
        {
            SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
            factory.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
            factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
            factory.setConcurrentConsumers(6); 
            factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(8);
            factory.setPrefetchCount(20);
            return factory; 
        }
@Bean(name = "productsimplecontainer") 
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory simpleProductListenerContainerFactory() throws Exception
    { 
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
        factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        factory.setConcurrentConsumers(3); 
        factory.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(4);
        factory.setPrefetchCount(20);
        return factory; 
    }
```

---

in the listener code i am passing the respective connection factory as shown below

```
@RabbitListener( queues = "<queueName>", containerFactory = "<factoryName>", autoStartup = "${autocreateworker}")
    public void myListener(SftpStockDailySyncAsyncRequest sftpStockDailySyncRequest) {
    }
```

The issue i had is at any given time only one queue is running and the other queues are in idle state and because of this important queues are waiting until they get chance to go to running state, the screen below depicts the scenario.

[image]

Please correct me on how to resolve this issue.

As of now I have two worker machines which are listening to RabbitMQ server.

Comment: can you try calling this endpoint `http://localhost:15672/api/queues`

Comment: also, have you confirmed if there is a consumer on other queues?

Comment: @VeKe , there are consumers on queues now, but some times, the consumers get  deleted even though there are messages present in queue.

Comment: @VeKe Even though i have configured two worker machines, some/most times only one worker handles all the tasks and the other worker sits idle.

Comment: maybe its due to a Disconnect interval. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=order-disconnect-interval-discint